# NSPredicate JOIN two table OBJECTIVE C

Tags: mysql, sql, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm working on an IPAD project, and I need to JOIN two table.
Because I have to fetch the JOIN result.

For Examples

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id2 = t2.id1
WHERE [condition]
```

How I can do that with NSPredicate?
And if is possibile create a View with this query?

Comment: how do you connect to mysql to use Predicate ? are you sure you are using MySQL ?

Comment: @ogres i use Mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `NSPredicate`

> Limitations: You cannot necessarily translate “arbitrary” SQL queries
>   into predicates or fetch requests. There is no way, for example, to
>   convert a SQL statement [...] into a fetch request. You must fetch the objects of interest, then either
>   perform a calculation directly using the results, or use an array
>   operator.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)